# Python check inline a value in a string and change it

Tags: python, string

In my python 3 project i have:

```
for a in range(len(eval(tmainl['t_ttk']))):    
    ttk_save = temp_test_keywords(key_val=eval(tmainl['t_ttk'])[a]['tk_kval'],
                              key_group=eval(tmainl['t_ttk'])[a]['tk_kgroup'],
                              key_id_id=last_key,
                              main_id_id=main_id,
                              test_id_id=case_id,
                              owner_id=1,
                              dt=str(datetime.now()))

     ttk_save.save()
```

well, i would to check inline if for example `eval(tmainl['t_ttk'])[a]['tk_kval']` has 'None' string as value and in case change with None (not str).
I try the get function but i don't know how can i search for a specific str.

Someone can explain me how to intercept inline 'None' str value and change to None directive?

So many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) to do this. Per your example, that would be

```
key_val = your_string if your_string != 'None' else None
```